# Pretty Tensor not working with Tensorflow 1.8

Tags: tensorflow, prettytensor

After upgrading to TF1.8, Pretty Tensor stopped working with the following error. It seems `_VARSCOPE_KEY` is removed from `variable_scope`.

```
.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/prettytensor/scopes.py in 
var_and_name_scope(names)
53 full_name = var_scope.name
54
---> 55 vs_key = tf.get_collection_ref(variable_scope._VARSCOPE_KEY)
56 try:
57 # TODO(eiderman): Remove this hack or fix the full file.

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope' has no attribute '_VARSCOPE_KEY'
```

Comment: Please provide an MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In the [package PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/prettytensor/), it is mentioned

> Last released: Feb 20, 2017

Similarly, from [Github](https://github.com/google/prettytensor), we see that the last commit was on Feb 1, 2017, regarding "a few more transformations in anticipation of TF1.0".

There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/google/prettytensor/issues/62) on the exact problem you describe.

The last reply to an issue from the package maintainers dates back to March 2017.

All the above are signs of a rather abandoned project, with its present status frozen before the release of Tensorflow 1.0. So, I seriously advise you to move on; if your codebase still have dependencies on this package, you can downgrade to version 1.7 of Tensorflow, which *seems* to work fine with Pretty Tensor...